# Scalable Way to Combine Same Requests Within Certain Time Threshold

Tags: java, synchronization, rx-java, reactive-programming, scalability

I have an application, call it Service 1, that potentially makes a lot of the same requests to another application, call it Service 2. As an example, x number of people use Service 1 and that results in x requests (which are the exact same request) to Service 2. Each response is cached in Service 1.

Currently, we have a synchronized method that checks whether or not the same request has been made within a certain time threshold. The problem we are having is that when the server is under a heavy load that synchronized method locks up the threads, kubernetes can't perform liveness checks, so kubernetes restarts the service. The reason we want to prevent duplicate requests is two fold: 1) we don't want to hammer service 2, and 2) if we already are making the request we don't want to make it again, just wait for the result that will already be coming back.

What is the fastest, most scalable solution to not making duplicate requests without locking up and taking down the server?

Comment: how do u identify whether the request is same or different?

Comment: Is there any reason that you're maintaining that cache on your own server, instead of a cache provider service like MemcacheD or Redis?

Comment: @NirajChauhan We know it is the same request because the request will create the same key and resource that goes into the cache.

Comment: @Jay we are using ehcache within app. Why? It's legacy

Comment: @jwill AFAIK, you can have EHCache running in a separate server and have your application connect to it using the multicast addresses. That way, you don't have to worry about caches being too big in your application. Let EHCache handle that.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, my experience with rx-java specifically is very limited, so I'm not entirely confident how applicable this is for your case. This is a solution I've used several times with Scala and I know Java itself does have analogous constructs that would allow the same approach.

A solution I have used in the past that has worked very well for me involves using Futures. It does not reduce duplication entirely, but it does remove duplication per requesting server. The approach involves using a TTL Cache in which we stored the Future object that does or will contain the result of a request we want to deduplicate on. It is stored under a key that can determine uniqueness of the request such as the different parameters that might be applicable.

So let's say you have a method that you call to fetch the response from Service 2 and returns it as a Future. As an example we'll say `getPage` which has one parameter, an integer, which is the page you'd like to fetch.

When a request begins and we're about to call getPage with the page number of 2, we check the cache for a key like "getPage:2". This won't contain anything for the first request, so we call `getPage(2)` which returns a `Future[SomeResponseObject]`. We set "getPage:2" in the TTL Cache to the Future object. When another request comes in that may spawn a duplicate request, the same cache check happens, however, there's a `Future` object already in the cache. We get this future and add a response listener to be invoked when the response is available, or in Scala, simply `.map()` on it.

This has a few advantages. If your request is slow or there's highly duplicative requests even in a small time frame, many requests to Service 1 are serviced by a single response from Service 2.

Secondarily, once the request to Service 2 has come back, assuming you have a window in which the response is still valid, the response is already available immediately and no request is necessary at all.

If your Service 2 request takes 50ms, and your response can be considered valid for 5 seconds, all requests happening to the same server in the first 50ms are serviced at ms 50 when the response is returned, and from that point forward for the remaining 4950 ms already have access to the response.

As I alluded earlier to the effectiveness here is tied to how many instances of Service 1 are running. The number of duplicate requests at any time is linear to the number of Servers running.

This is a mostly lock free way to achieve this. I saw *mostly* because some synchronization is necessary the TTL Cache itself to make sure the request is only started once, but has never been an issue for performance in my experience.

---

As an extension of this, you can potentially use something like redis to cache responses from Service 2 if it has long-ish response times, and have your `getPage` equivalent first check a redis cache for the serialized response (and write an expiring value if one wasn't there). This allows you to further reduce requests to Service 2 by having a more global value cached, but having a second caching layer does add some complexity and potential for issues.